# Can not instantiate value of type from json string

Tags: java, json, jackson, jax-rs

I have bidirection many to many relationship between users and groups .

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "UserTBL")
    public class User {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "user_generator", sequenceName = "user_seq", allocationSize = 1, initialValue = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "user_generator")
    private Long id;

    private String username;

    private String password;

    @ManyToMany
    private List<Group> groups;
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "GroupTBL")
public class Group {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "Group_generator", sequenceName = "group_seq", allocationSize = 1, initialValue = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "Group_generator")
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    private String description;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "groups")
    private List<User> users;
}
```

I am developing angular js  applicaton with  java jax-rs web service and I am handling json binding using jackson but i am getting this exception :

**Can not instantiate value of type [simple type, class com.blog.models.Group] from JSON String; no single-String constructor/factory method (through reference chain: com.blog.models.User["groups"])**

This is my json object sent to the server :

```
{  
   "groups":[  
      "{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"admin\",\"description\":null,\"users\":[]}",
      "{\"id\":2,\"name\":\"user\",\"description\":null,\"users\":[]}"
   ],
   "username":"hussien",
   "password":"ammar"
}
```

Resource :

```
@Stateless
@Path("/users")
public class UserResource {

    @EJB
    private UserFacade userFacade;

    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public void createUser(User user) {
        userFacade.create(user);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like on the client side you might be stringifying your JSON object twice (the groups).  You should only call this once.  This is how the JSON should come over:

```
{"groups":[
{"id":1,"name":"admin","description":null,"users":[]},
{"id":2,"name":"user","description":null,"users":[]}
],
"username":"hussien",
"password":"ammar"
}
```

Comment: I test it using advanced rest client chrome extension and the same exception appear

Comment: your answer worked for me but I am confused why my json didn't work although it is valid

Comment: It's valid JSON, but not the JSON that your app is expecting.  That would map as a `List<String>` where the first entry is the first string there, and the second the second value.

Comment: FINALLY!!! I've been dealing with an issue for 4 hours, first my controller wasn't being invoked, then I changed it to receive a LinkedHashMap instead of my POJO but couldn't map it myself with ObjectMapper... it all was caused by my JS objects being stringifyed twice. Thanks!